# using c++ turn a text file into a adjacency list

Tags: c++

Let's say you were given a text file with two columns like so:
commas represent a new line: --------------
blue green,
blue red,
red orange,
red purple,
and so on...

how could would you turn this into an adjacency list
with size n and the type of the array being a list of vertices.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help:

`main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Item
{
    std::string first;
    std::string second;
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("input.txt");

    std::vector<Item> items;

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line))
    {
        Item item;
        size_t p_space = line.find_first_of(' ');
        if(p_space == line.npos){
            //error: no space between two column
        }
        item.first = line.substr(0, p_space);
        item.second = line.substr(p_space + 1, line.size() - p_space - 1);
        items.push_back(item);
    }

    for (const auto &item : items)
        std::cout << item.first << ": " << item.second << "\n";
}
```

`input.txt`:

```
blue green
blue red
red orange
red purple
```